# How to use Command-Line Debugger .NET

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a wpf app that runs ok on my win 10 but on win server it breaks if I resize the window, so I'm trying to find a way to know about witch exeption there is.

I read a little about [MDbg.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861(VS.80).aspx) but I didn't understand how to use it, should I install something? to add some code to my app?

If I'm asking... why the app breaks when resizing the window only on win server 2012 but on my win10 all is ok?

Comment: Do you have a global exception handler? What does your application log say when the exception comes up?

Comment: Maybe it's unhandled exeption that I missed and didn't write log about

Comment: I mean the Windows Application log, Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer

Comment: If an unhandled exception causes a process to die, Windows writes an event to the event log.